# How do I use itertool with tuples to move joints to different locations?

Tags: python, maya

I just started learning some Python for rigging and my university doesn't really focus on that and I am getting a bit confused with few code combinations I am trying to use.

I want to move lots of joints to different location for each one of them and instead of going cmds.move() 20 times in a row I want to use iteritems with tuples to make my lines cleaner.

This is my tiny piece of code in Python:

```
# import commands from maya package
from maya import cmds

moveTailJoints = {
    'tail_001_jnt': {(0, 2.607, -20.579)},
}

for driver, driven in moveTailJoints.iteritems():
    cmds.move(
        driver.format(),
        driven.format()
    )
```

Is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure what `cmds.move` is doing. Are you trying to manipulate the `tuple` at `tail_001_jnt` such that all of the components are switched around?

Comment: I am trying to move tail_001_jnt to those specific coordinates and cmds.move is the command for Maya Python to do it.

Comment: Can you show us how would you call `cmds.move` a single time? I mean, how would you move the item in your example? Is it `cmds.move(0, 2.607, -20.579)` ?

Comment: is your tail_001 and tail_002 are related in positionning, if not you can just use cmds.setAttr() and change the translate value

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

A few things:
You don't need that nested dictionary around your position value `{(0, 2.607, -20.579)}`, as it serves no purpose.

You can loop through both the objects and positions by using `dict`'s built in `.items()` method.

You're not very clear here, but I'm assuming those position values are world coordinates? If so, then you need to include the absolute flag in the `cmds.move` method. Alternatively, you can also use `cmds.xform` to move an object to a world space position.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

moveTailJoints = {
    'tail_001_jnt':(0, 1, 0),
    'tail_002_jnt':(0, 2, 0),
    'tail_003_jnt':(0, 3, 0),
    'tail_004_jnt':(0, 4, 0)   
}

for obj, pos in moveTailJoints.items():
    tx, ty, tz = pos
    cmds.move(tx, ty, tz, obj, a=True)
```

Check out the Maya docs for more examples on command usage:

http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/ENU/?guid=__CommandsPython_index_html